# How do I find the intersection of a 3D line and a sphere?

Tags: geometry, 3d, spheres

I have a sphere with center $(0, 0, A)$ and radius $A$. I also have a point-vector equation for a line in 3D space:

$$
X = (x_0, y_0, z_0) + λ \begin{pmatrix}\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{2} ×& \frac{z_1 − z_0}{y_1 − y_0} + \frac{z_2 − z_0}{y_2 − y_0}, \\
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} ×& \frac{z_1 − z_0}{y_1 − y_0}, \\
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} ×& \frac{z_1 − z_0}{y_1 − y_0} × \frac{z_2 − z_0}{y_2 − y_0}
\end{aligned}\end{pmatrix}
$$

The point $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ lies on the surface of the sphere, so it is one intersection point between the line and the sphere. I want to find the other intersection point between the line and the sphere. How do I do that?

Comment: And what you have tried to solve this problem ?  It is important on math.stackexchange.com to include your own effort at solving or attempting to solve your problem.  This will give your question substance and context.  Without that, your question is likely to get downvoted and/or be closed for answering.

Comment: @HosamHAJEER Why did you delete your answer? I read up on vector mathematics, figured out how to use the information you provided, and thus found that your answer was correct. Can you re-post your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Sure, I'll undelete it.  But please next time you post a question, make sure to include your effort to solve it.  This is considered crucially important on this site, for the question to be considered a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation of the sphere is

$ x^2 + y^2 + (z - A)^2 = A^2 $

if you let $ r = [x, y, z]^T $ and $r_1 = [0, 0, A]^T $, then in vector form, the equation is

$ (r - r_1) \cdot (r - r_1) = A^2 $

In addition to that, you have the line

$ L(\lambda) = L_0 + \lambda V $

where $L_0 = [x_0 , y_0 , z_0 ]^T $ , and $V $ is a known vector that depends on $ y_0, y_1, y_2 , z_0, z_1, z_2 $.

Plug in the equation of the line into the equation of the sphere

$ (L_0 + \lambda V - r_1) \cdot (L_0 + \lambda V - r_1) = A^2 $

And it is given that $L_0$ lies on the sphere, that is

$ (L_0 - r_1) \cdot (L_0 - r_1) = A^2 $

Then by expanding this expression, you get

$ (L_0 - r_1 ) \cdot (L_0 - r_1) +  2 \lambda \ V \cdot (L_0 - r_1) + \lambda^2 V \cdot V = A^2 $

Since $(L_0 - r_1) \cdot (L_0 - r_1) = A^2 $, then

$ 2 \lambda \ V \cdot (L_0 - r_1) + \lambda^2 V \cdot V = 0 $

Which has two solutions, $\lambda = 0 $ (and this corresponds to the point $L_0$) and

$ \lambda = - 2 \dfrac{ V \cdot (L_0 - r_1) }{V \cdot V} $

And this value corresponds to the second point of intersection.

Substitute this value into the equation of the line to get the coordinates of the second point of intersection.

Comment: I'm not well-versed in mathematics with vectors, so I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but when I try to work out the coordinates of the second point of intersection with the expression from your answer, all the $V$s seem to cancel out, giving a result that is entirely independent of the direction of the line: $L_0 + λ V = L_0 - 2 \frac{V \cdot (L_0 - r_1)}{V \cdot V} V = L_0 - 2 (L_0 - r_1) = [-x_0, -y_0, -z_0 + 2 A]^T$. That doesn't make sense. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: $ \dfrac{ V \cdot (L_0 - r_1)  V}{V \cdot V} \ne (L_0 - r_1) $